# How can pull (checkout) any set of files in Git version Control?

Tags: xcode, git, version-control

There was 50 files in an on-going project, example. I wanted to checkout file 1 version 1, file 2 version 2, file 3 version 3, ...., file 50 version 50, to cloned a customed version of project.
How can do this ?
(I am using Git on XCode 4.5)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

```
git checkout [some-older-commit-ref] a-file
```

Just do that for each file.

Answer (score 0):

That is a very strange thing to do. Any modern VCS is set to track the state of a *project*, i.e., the contents of the full set of files at a point in time. If you regularly need to mix and match different versions of files, perhaps you should rethink what you are doing. I can only assume you don't really need a bizarre sequence as above, so:

- Identify the sets of files that are used together at the same version (probably you can do so by thinking about the different types of "builds")
- Create a branch for each variant collection of file versions
- Perhaps create a "master development" branch on which to create new versions of the files, and cherry pick from it? Or a development branch for each bundle of files, and pick up versions from it for each "build"?